# GIS Stack Exchange Blog - Stats

Tags: discussion, blog

**strong text**Thanks to Matt Wilkie  'It’s all about the data' The blog has had is best day in terms of hits

Note: planetgs.com (James Fee) has added GIS SE to the blog aggregator.

Notable is Social Media Twitter for hits.

[image]

updated stats to represent Kirks recent post - again the spike from new posts - sources again are GIS SE blog and Twitter.

[image]

So for the Question (as Meta)

**How does everyone feel about this?
Can 'we' the community do more to build a successful blog?
Are there more contributors out there that want to help?
comments/answers please**

Comment: Looks like the Blog link at the top now goes to the GIS.se blog instead of the general SE blog, so that's a great improvement.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I finally got around to publishing [the post](http://gis.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/calculation-compilation-and-communication/) I started on several weeks ago. I notice the date reflects when I started, not when I published.  Is this why no new blog link appears at the top of the page?

Comment: ok, I copied and pasted old post to a new post and deleted the old one.  The new post has today's date.

Comment: Kirk RSS feeds picked up both your post (older now deleted and new post). both links point to the new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we should open up blogging to all users that meet some threshold rep.  Dump wordpress and give every qualified user their own blog that they can access from a new tab next to their profile.

Posting to a blog would be a lot like posting a question, except that blogs can only be edited by the author.  Make the same tags that are available to questions available for the blog.  Reward rep to authors when their posts are upvoted.

Add a new tab next to Questions called BlogPosts.  Readers will be able to:

- sort blog posts by votes, active, newest
- up/down vote other people's blog posts
- post responses
- up/down vote others' responses

With the right incentives, I think blogs could become a home for canonical answers. If a blog references a question, there would be a link back to it from the sidebar.  Likewise, if a question references a blog, there would be a link back to it from the sidebar.

Comment: This would be amazing.

Comment: +1 That would be a great feature indeed. How it would play out in the long run I'm not sure. How responsible will people use it?

Comment: good ideas - look forward to them being implemented.